# stack Push Method

Tags: c#

```
class Node
{
object data;
Node nextNode;

}

class stack
{
Node top;

public push()
{

Node aNewNode = new Node();
aNewNode.nextNode = top;
top = aNewNode;

}

}
```

can anybody tell why we assign top= aNewNode

Comment: Because...it's a stack? Is this homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the last inserted node in a stack becomes the first that is retrieved ([LIFO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29)) - so it is the new "top" of the stack.

It works like a stack of cards that you throw cards on top - when you deal cards now the last card you added to the top is the first you deal.

Comment: Node aNode = new Node() // this represents a new node, when the stack is empty and the first element is pushed, aNode.NextNode = top, and again top = aNode , why aNode is assigned back to the top

Comment: @Raghav: `aNode.NextNode = top` says link this new node to the existing top node - so once you pull this node you now which node is next. `top = aNewNode;` then assigns the **new** top to be the new node It's a linked list of node going from the top node down to the oldest node.

Comment: little confused when the same code is written in C++   Node temp = new node() ; temp->nextnode = top and top = temp, top and temp->nextnode and temp all point to the same memory location if we change one  the other will be affected this is my understanding is correct.

Comment: @Raghav: No that is incorrect: `temp->nextNode` points to the **old** top, a different memory location - we have not updated `top` yet. Then we assign the memory location of the **new** node `temp` to the  the variable `top` - after this `top` points to the newly added node. At the start of the method it was pointing to the node added **the last time** push was called (the previous "top")

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse stacks are a "Last In, First Out" aka LIFO data structure.

Similar to the little metal spikes you see diners put receipts on.

Answer (score 0):

A stack is a last-in, first-out structure. This means that to add a new item to that stack, you reference the top item, assign that to your new node as the previous top, and then set your new node as the logical top. Any work, such as enumeration, adding or removing always starts with the head.

Answer (score 0):

It is basic functionality of a Stack - "Last IN, First OUT".

Your top in stack is always the newNode which is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes are the elements in the stack and your implementation is based on a linked list.

Therefore to push a new element on the stack, you create a new node. Then a link from the new node to the previous top. Ie. the new node becomes the new top. Hence the assignment, so that you can keep track of the top.

Note that the implementation you've posted does not need to keep track of the stack's bottom. However, a POP function should check for this by checking the calling application is not attempting to 'pop' the end null.

Answer (score 0):

Because a stack is a LIFO (last in, first out) data structure, when calling push(), you are creating a new node, which will be on the top, because it should be the first one removed if you were to call pop().  When pushing, you would link the current top object to the new nodes nextNode property and set the the stack's top property to the new node.

Answer (score 0):

You have an existing stack (which is implemented as a linked list here) which is:
    B -> C -> D -> E
where B is at the top and B's nextNode is C and so forth.

When you push something onto the stack, it becomes the new "top".  So you have to do two things: 1) Make the existing top of the stack be the nextNode of that new top of the stack, and 2) Set the stack's idea of the top of the stack to refer to that new top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you're implementing a LIFO stack and using a singly linked list as the underlying implementation, prepending the new node to the head of the list is

- the simplest way of doing it, and doing so
- makes `push()` and `pop()` O(1) operations.

Otherwise, adding/removing items from the stack require iterating over the entire list, making `push()` and `pop()` O(N) operations. Or you could use a doubly-linked list as the underlying datastore for the stack, at the expense of more memory (2 pointers per node vs. 1  pointer per node), and complicating the implementation of `push()` and `pop()`.

Using a doubly-linked list, though, means, that by adding 2 more methods, , you get a lot more versatility out of your class: you can use the same class as a stack, a queue, or some combination. Perl's arrays, for instance, are implemented as linked lists and provide `push` and `pop` operations for adding/removings items from the end of the array, and `shift` and `unshift` operations for doing the same to the beginning of the array. To use a perl array as a stack, you use `push`/`pop`; to use it as a queue, you use `push`/`shift` (or `unshift`/`pop` if you're so inclined.)